# Strange Behaviour with Devel Version of Dplyr when Using Count and Mutate to Calculate Percentages

Tags: r, debugging, dplyr, percentage

[image]

The dplyr code below produces the output pictured above with the exception that the percentage column is not showing the correct percentage breakdown. I believe using dplyr::count should group by happy, then key, then value, which is what it did when I ran the code before installing the new packages. So I'm wondering if count is calculating differently? I'm just trying to reproduce the same output I got previously while using a different dplyr.

I'm not sure if it's related to the devel version of dplyr. The code below worked before I installed dplyr from `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")Around the same time I also installed the new forcats and tibble packages. I also installed RTools.

On the first try loading the new dplyr failed because I didn't have "bindrcpp" or "bindr"...not sure if need both, but I installed both packages separately, then was able to successfuly install dplyr.

I'm new to reporting an issue like this so let me know if there's anything else I should include!

```
# Data is the 'happy' dataset from the ggmosaic package

happy %>%
  select(sex, happy, marital, health, degree) %>%
  gather(key, value, -happy) %>%
  count(happy, key, value) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mutate(perc = round(n/sum(n),2))
```

Versions: `R 3.3.2, tidyr 0.6.0, tibble 1.2, ggmosaic 0.1.1, ggplot2 2.2.0, forcats-0.1.1` (not used in this example but I installed the new version recently)

Code came from a previous question - "Functional programming with Tidyr's “gather” and Ggplot2 for More Rapid Visual Data Exploration"

Comment: **This is not a reproducible example! Please create an MRE**, either use `dput()` on your tibble, or post code that creates it with seeded-random values. Prune the example down to the absolute minimum needed to repro the bug.

Comment: Next, *"it doesn't caculate the percentages correctly. Everything works but the `mutate()` line."* tells us nearly nothing (gross error? double precision error? something else?). Post the results you get (on the reproducible data), and if there's an error message, post it too.

Comment: Also, post your version of R and all relevant packages: dplyr, tidyr, and any other dependencies this code uses. And your OS platform and version. Have you tried to repro on other versions of R or platforms? This is all standard bug-triage/reporting stuff...

Comment: My apologies! I wrote this too fast...I added more information. I usually just ask code-related questions so I'm not as familair with how to report something that is not working how it should...let me know if there's anything else I can add.

Comment: *"Data is the happy dataset from the ggmosaic package."* Listen, we're not installing extra packages just to repro one possible bug that might only occur in some devel build. I want to see `require`,`dput`,`structure()` commands giving me **reproducible data**. Or inevitably people start downvoting. *"The percentage column is not showing correct percentages."* But what is it showing? (Is this yet another question about numerical precision, rounding and formatting?) Please actually **post a snippet of output**, like I asked. Prune it to the minimum necessary for reproducibility.

Comment: You probably also want to search for and look into all the (many) existing duplicates on `dplyr, options()` and formatting, if it's a suspected numerical precision issue. When I had similar issues, 90% of the time those were the culprit.

Comment: Also, package names in R are all case-sensitive, I had to edit yours. And I moved a clear concise statement of the bug to the first sentence. *"Experiencing some weird behavior"* doesn't communicate anything, it makes us scream inwardly :)

Comment: Have you tried `round(n/sum(n),10))` to eliminate numeric rounding?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the output. Thanks for all the help! I

Comment: I want the first five percentages (not too happy and degree) to be - 0.08, 0.04, 0.49, 0.04, 0.36.

Comment: You still haven't given us **reproducible data**, I explained what you needed to post, we're not installing ggmosaic; at least please use a builtin R dataset like dplyr's `nycflights13`. As to triaging your bug, please rollback your dplyr to latest release and tell us if the bug only occurs in devel? If yes, please [file an issue on dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues); search their existing issues first to make sure this isn't known already.